# How to use stroke feature in material design?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

what is purpose of stroke here :

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/rippleEffectColor"
xmlns:tools="ht-- tp://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:targetApi="lollipop">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/signin"></solid>
        <corners android:radius="4dp"></corners>
        <stroke android:color="@color/yellow"></stroke>
    </shape>
</item>
```

because the ripple effect is done by the `android:colour="@colour/rippleEffectColor"`

Comment: @colour/rippleEffectColor   can u share color code

Comment: stroke is the border color of rect.  https://android.jlelse.eu/android-shape-drawables-tutorial-17fbece6fef5 more info